# I need to pass an ifstream into a function so i can add it to a vector

Tags: function, visual-c++, vector, ifstream

I'm very new to programming and need some help, thanks!

I have a text file named namelist.txt. I need to pass inFile to a function that can add the list of names (in the format of firstname lastname, ex: chuck norris) to a vector called vecStudent. how do you pass inFile to a function and if possible how would i add the names to a vector?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

ifstream readtoVec(); //function prototypes
int displayAll();
int add();
int remove();
int savequit();

int main()
{
char cInput;
string strFileName;
vector<string> vecStudent;
ifstream inFile;
ofstream outFile;

{
    cout << "Please Enter the data file name (with location): ";
    cin >> strFileName;

    inFile.open(strFileName.c_str());

    if (inFile.fail())

    {
        cout << "Input file error!" << endl;

        return -1;
    }

    // call a function to read the contents of the input file into vecStudent
    else
    {
        readtoVec (ifstream& inFile);
```

I'm getting an error here called "type name is not allowed"

```
}



while (true)
{
    cout << "--------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << " Student Record - Main Menu " << endl;
    cout << "--------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << " Enter 1 to display ALL students " << endl;
    cout << " Enter 2 to add a student name " << endl;
    cout << " Enter 3 to delete a student name " << endl;
    cout << " Enter 4 to SAVE and quit the program " << endl;
    cout << "--------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << " Enter menu option: " ;
    cin >> cInput;
    switch (cInput)
    {
        case '1':
            //call function
            break;
        case '2':
            //call function
            break;
        case '3':
            //call function
            break;
        case '4':
            //call function
            return 0;
        default:
            cout << "invalid input" << endl;
            break;
    }

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> ifstream readtoVec(); //function prototypes

This says `readtoVec()` returns an `ifstream`, and doesn't take any arguments but here:

> readtoVec (ifstream& inFile);

You're (sort of) trying to pass an argument when you call `readtoVec`. At least based on how you're trying to call it, the declaration should be something like `void readtoVec(ifstream &);`

When you do call that, you do *not* specify the type of the parameter though, so the call would look like: `readtoVec(inFile);`

Comment: thanks for the reply, how would i then add the list of names inside the .txt file to a vector inside the function readtoVec? i thought void doesnt return anything to then main.